# FailoverClientConnectionFactory: Connected with fail-over server but still trying to connect with primary server

Tags: spring-integration

I am having an issue if connection getting dropped with primary server and fail-over server is also not up. After some time fail-over server getting up and connection getting successfully established with Server fail-over. But still its trying to connect with Primary server, is this desired behavior?

Code snippet for connection factory:

List processServers = mConfigurationService.getProcessServers();
            List factories = new ArrayList<>();

```
        for (ServerInfo serverInfo : processServers) 
        {
            AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientFactory = new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory(
                    serverInfo.getServerAddress(), serverInfo.getServerPort());
            clientFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(this.applicationEventPublisher);             
            clientFactory.setSingleUse(false);
            clientFactory.setDeserializer(mMessageSerializerDeserializer);
            clientFactory.setSerializer(mMessageSerializerDeserializer);
            factories.add(clientFactory);
        }

        failoverCF = new FailoverClientConnectionFactory(factories);
        failoverCF.setSingleUse(false);
        failoverCF.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Here are the logs, where we can see that connection is established with 10.90.x.F, but it still trying to connect with 10.90.x.P.

> 2020-02-27 16:33:53 [task-scheduler-10] DEBUG
>   o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory - Opening new socket
>   connection to 10.90.x.P:42027 2020-02-27 16:33:53 [task-scheduler-2]
>   DEBUG
>   o.s.i.i.t.c.FailoverClientConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection -
>   org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory@4946485c,
>   host=10.90.x.P, port=42027 failed with java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection timed out: connect, trying another 2020-02-27 16:33:53
>   [task-scheduler-2] DEBUG
>   o.s.i.i.t.c.FailoverClientConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection -
>   Got
>   10.90.x.F:42027:65437:1f582e09-eb9a-4966-8fd2-60cb156ad015
>   from
>   org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory@1df06ecd,
>   host=10.90.x.F, port=42027 2020-02-27 16:33:53 [task-scheduler-2]
>   DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.ClientModeConnectionManager - Connection
>   bae635ce-c643-4650-ba15-5fb2fe8af053:1 established 2020-02-27 16:34:14
>   [task-scheduler-10] DEBUG
>   o.s.i.i.t.c.FailoverClientConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection -
>   org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory@4946485c,
>   host=10.90.x.P, port=42027 failed with java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection timed out: connect, trying another 2020-02-27 16:34:14
>   [task-scheduler-7] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory -
>   Opening new socket connection to 10.90.x.P:42027 2020-02-27 16:34:14
>   [task-scheduler-10] DEBUG
>   o.s.i.i.t.c.FailoverClientConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection -
>   Got
>   10.90.x.F:42027:65437:1f582e09-eb9a-4966-8fd2-60cb156ad015
>   from
>   org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory@1df06ecd,
>   host=10.90.x.F, port=42027 2020-02-27 16:34:14 [task-scheduler-10]
>   DEBUG o.s.i.i.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler - Got Connection
>   7a451368-13b2-4abf-908e-3cfe0fca2148:1
>
> 2020-02-27 16:34:35 [task-scheduler-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.i.i.t.c.FailoverClientConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection -
>   org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory@4946485c,
>   host=10.90.x.P, port=42027 failed with java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection timed out: connect, trying another 2020-02-27 16:34:35
>   [task-scheduler-7] DEBUG
>   o.s.i.i.t.c.FailoverClientConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection -
>   Got
>   10.90.x.F:42027:65437:1f582e09-eb9a-4966-8fd2-60cb156ad015
>   from
>   org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory@1df06ecd,
>   host=10.90.x.F, port=42027

New logs with sample project:

```
2020-03-04 21:57:39.027  INFO 76636 --- [           main] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : started server2, port=1235
Hit enter to start server1
2020-03-04 21:57:39.029  INFO 76636 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : server2, port=1235 Listening
2020-03-04 21:57:39.081 DEBUG 76636 --- [ask-scheduler-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory : client2: Added new connection: localhost:1235:52400:26295f67-0ebf-45bd-b7f9-ad7d6a08ffbf
2020-03-04 21:57:39.084 DEBUG 76636 --- [ask-scheduler-1] tConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection : Got localhost:1235:52400:26295f67-0ebf-45bd-b7f9-ad7d6a08ffbf from client2, host=localhost, port=1235
ee1cbb1c-0ae0-49b3-969a-38cf28ed6aea:1
2:[B@53ec43e4
ee1cbb1c-0ae0-49b3-969a-38cf28ed6aea:2
2:[B@1da20d77
ee1cbb1c-0ae0-49b3-969a-38cf28ed6aea:3
2:[B@6acde81
2020-03-04 21:57:54.096 DEBUG 76636 --- [ask-scheduler-3] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory : Opening new socket connection to localhost:1234
2020-03-04 21:57:56.102 DEBUG 76636 --- [ask-scheduler-3] tConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection : client1, host=localhost, port=1234 failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect, trying another
2020-03-04 21:57:56.103 DEBUG 76636 --- [ask-scheduler-3] tConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection : Got localhost:1235:52400:26295f67-0ebf-45bd-b7f9-ad7d6a08ffbf from client2, host=localhost, port=1235
8bfe4fab-1931-4565-af56-f162252f972b:1
2:[B@46fd87cc
8bfe4fab-1931-4565-af56-f162252f972b:2
2:[B@77bf1f94
```

Comment: Edit the question to show your connection factory configuration. If you are using single use connections (one connection per request) then, yes, the factory will keep trying both each time a new connection is requested.

Comment: No, I am using single use as false. Updated code snippet with question.

Comment: And spring-integration-ip version is 4.3.2.

Comment: Your log doesn't show any attempts to connect to the P server after the connection to F is opened. 4.3.2 is nearly 4 years old; the current version is 5.2.4; the latest 4.3.x version is 4.3.21 you should at least upgrade to that, even if you can't upgrade to a more recent major/minor version.

Comment: As we can see in logs, its still trying to connect to the P server:

Comment: 2020-02-27 16:34:14 [task-scheduler-7] DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory - Opening new socket connection to 10.90.x.P:42027

Comment: I ran scenarios with 4.3.21 but found same result. We can see that there are different task-schedulers while its trying to connect to P server. Scheduler should not be stopped if its connected with F server?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your patience; I reproduced it.

It's a bug https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3199

**EDIT**

New properties to control this behavior:

```
/**
 * When using a shared connection {@link #setSingleUse(boolean) singleUse} is false,
 * specify how long to wait before trying to fail back to start from the beginning of
 * the factory list. Default is 0 for backwards compatibility to always try to get a
 * connection to the primary server. If you don't want to fail back until the current
 * connection is closed, set this to {@link Long#MAX_VALUE}.
 * Cannot be changed when using {@link CachingClientConnectionFactory} delegates.
 * @param refreshSharedInterval the interval in milliseconds.
 * @since 4.3.22
 * @see #setSingleUse(boolean)
 * @see #setCloseOnRefresh(boolean)
 */
public void setRefreshSharedInterval(long refreshSharedInterval) {
    Assert.isTrue(!this.cachingDelegates,
            "'refreshSharedInterval' cannot be changed when using 'CachingClientConnectionFactory` delegates");
    this.refreshSharedInterval = refreshSharedInterval;
}

/**
 * When using a shared connection {@link #setSingleUse(boolean) singleUse} is false,
 * set this to true to close the old shared connection after a refresh. If this is
 * false, the connection will remain open, but unused until its connection factory is
 * again used to get a connection. Default is false for backwards compatibility.
 * Cannot be changed when using {@link CachingClientConnectionFactory} delegates.
 * @param closeOnRefresh true to close.
 * @since 4.3.22
 * @see #setSingleUse(boolean)
 * @see #setRefreshSharedInterval(long)
 */
public void setCloseOnRefresh(boolean closeOnRefresh) {
    Assert.isTrue(!this.cachingDelegates,
            "'closeOnRefresh' cannot be changed when using 'CachingClientConnectionFactory` delegates");
    this.closeOnRefresh = closeOnRefresh;
}
```

**EDIT2**

Aside from the [unit tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/fa0caeb1b4e7b27bd7723b826e81ddb962d5a1a0#diff-6a67bffed44e68d81ae7558d856ca595), I tested the fix with the app I wrote to reproduce your issue:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class So60432039Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So60432039Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory server1() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(1234);
        factory.registerListener(m -> {
            System.out.println("1:" + m.getPayload());
            return false;
        });
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory server2() {
        TcpNetServerConnectionFactory factory = new TcpNetServerConnectionFactory(1235);
        factory.registerListener(m -> {
            System.out.println("2:" + m.getPayload());
            return false;
        });
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory client1() {
        return new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("localhost", 1234);
    }

    @Bean
    public AbstractClientConnectionFactory client2() {
        return new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("localhost", 1235);
    }

    @Bean
    public FailoverClientConnectionFactory failover() {
        FailoverClientConnectionFactory factory =
                new FailoverClientConnectionFactory(Arrays.asList(client1(), client2()));
        factory.registerListener(m -> false);
        factory.setRefreshSharedInterval(15_000);
        factory.setCloseOnRefresh(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5_000, initialDelay = 5_000)
    public void getConnection() throws Exception {
        try {
            TcpConnectionSupport connection = failover().getConnection();
            connection.send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
            System.out.println(connection.getConnectionId());
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner() {
        return args -> {
            client1().start();
            client2().start();
            failover().start();
            System.out.println("Hit enter to start server2");
            System.in.read();
            server2().start();
            System.out.println("Hit enter to start server1");
            System.in.read();
            server1().start();
            System.out.println("Hit enter to stop server1");
            System.in.read();
            server1().stop();
        };
    }

}
```

```
logging.level.org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory=debug
logging.level.org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.FailoverClientConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection=debug
```

With the `factory.setRefreshSharedInterval(15_000);` in place; I get:

```
Hit enter to start server2
<enter>
2020-03-03 09:23:36.065  INFO 78635 --- [           main] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : started server2, port=1235
Hit enter to start server1
2020-03-03 09:23:36.066  INFO 78635 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : server2, port=1235 Listening
2020-03-03 09:23:38.690 DEBUG 78635 --- [ask-scheduler-2] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory : Opening new socket connection to localhost:1234
2020-03-03 09:23:38.695 DEBUG 78635 --- [ask-scheduler-2] tConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection : client1, host=localhost, port=1234 failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), trying another
2020-03-03 09:23:38.695 DEBUG 78635 --- [ask-scheduler-2] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory : Opening new socket connection to localhost:1235
2020-03-03 09:23:38.697 DEBUG 78635 --- [ask-scheduler-2] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory : client2: Added new connection: localhost:1235:52647:f370c7e4-2455-4114-9c7a-55bd38f728cf
2020-03-03 09:23:38.698 DEBUG 78635 --- [ask-scheduler-2] tConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection : Got localhost:1235:52647:f370c7e4-2455-4114-9c7a-55bd38f728cf from client2, host=localhost, port=1235
2053c07b-3d7c-4ac0-8b46-1e2f703fa6a9:1
2:[B@7d7d9ef3
2053c07b-3d7c-4ac0-8b46-1e2f703fa6a9:2
2:[B@3316e0a4
2053c07b-3d7c-4ac0-8b46-1e2f703fa6a9:3
2:[B@2dae23bc
```

With it commented out, I get the old behavior:

```
Hit enter to start server2
<enter>
2020-03-03 09:25:45.143  INFO 79176 --- [           main] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : started server2, port=1235
Hit enter to start server1
2020-03-03 09:25:45.144  INFO 79176 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetServerConnectionFactory : server2, port=1235 Listening
2020-03-03 09:25:47.363 DEBUG 79176 --- [ask-scheduler-2] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory : Opening new socket connection to localhost:1234
2020-03-03 09:25:47.368 DEBUG 79176 --- [ask-scheduler-2] tConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection : client1, host=localhost, port=1234 failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), trying another
2020-03-03 09:25:47.368 DEBUG 79176 --- [ask-scheduler-2] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory : Opening new socket connection to localhost:1235
2020-03-03 09:25:47.369 DEBUG 79176 --- [ask-scheduler-2] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory : client2: Added new connection: localhost:1235:52775:31caf4d1-0fd1-49bf-8be6-f9fa935bd8a0
2020-03-03 09:25:47.371 DEBUG 79176 --- [ask-scheduler-2] tConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection : Got localhost:1235:52775:31caf4d1-0fd1-49bf-8be6-f9fa935bd8a0 from client2, host=localhost, port=1235
618d04e0-aa3a-4bac-966c-982d93528dd9:1
2:[B@47858489
2020-03-03 09:25:52.373 DEBUG 79176 --- [ask-scheduler-1] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory : Opening new socket connection to localhost:1234
2020-03-03 09:25:52.374 DEBUG 79176 --- [ask-scheduler-1] tConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection : client1, host=localhost, port=1234 failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), trying another
2020-03-03 09:25:52.374 DEBUG 79176 --- [ask-scheduler-1] tConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection : Got localhost:1235:52775:31caf4d1-0fd1-49bf-8be6-f9fa935bd8a0 from client2, host=localhost, port=1235
51b1c8ab-15c6-4108-acb7-b34584bf8506:1
2:[B@79bc08ef
2020-03-03 09:25:57.378 DEBUG 79176 --- [ask-scheduler-2] .s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory : Opening new socket connection to localhost:1234
2020-03-03 09:25:57.378 DEBUG 79176 --- [ask-scheduler-2] tConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection : client1, host=localhost, port=1234 failed with java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), trying another
2020-03-03 09:25:57.379 DEBUG 79176 --- [ask-scheduler-2] tConnectionFactory$FailoverTcpConnection : Got localhost:1235:52775:31caf4d1-0fd1-49bf-8be6-f9fa935bd8a0 from client2, host=localhost, port=1235
3c49c6f7-fe6a-410b-acff-cfa20aba42b1:1
2:[B@774d8ab2
```

**EDIT3**

Here is the pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>so60432039</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>so60432039</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-ip</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.22.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. Just wanted to know if there would be Release build available for 4.3.x with this change.

Comment: We will probably do a 4.3.22.RELEASE build soon; we may need to backport another fix first. In the meantime, you can test with 4.3.22.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from the spring snapshots repo. When do you need a release for production?

Comment: Bear in mind, though that SI 4.3.x will only be supported through the end of this year, since [Spring framework 4.3.x goes EOL at that time](https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/03/spring-framework-maintenance-roadmap-in-2020-including-4-3-eol). You should plan on upgrading to 5.2 (or 5.3) before the end of the year.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I tried to running with 4.3.22.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version, but getting same behavior. It still trying to connect with P Server even connection with F server.

Comment: See the documentation changes in [the pull request that fixes that issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3200). We had to retain the existing behavior by default, for backwards compatibility. I edited the answer to show the javadocs.

Comment: Ok, thanks Gary. I will check by setting these properties. I need release build as well, as soon as it possible for production.

Comment: Gary, I ran some scenarios by setting both of the properties setRefreshSharedInterval(Long.MAX_VALUE) and setCloseOnRefresh(true) but still getting same result. It still trying to connection with primary server. Can you please have a look if I am missing something.

Comment: I think you must be missing something; I edited my answer to show how I tested it; if you still can't figure it out, post a small standalone project someplace that reproduces it.

Comment: Gary, I can see same issue with the sample you provided if running it with 4.3.22.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version for spring-integration-ip. Its not making any difference if setting those properties.

Comment: Which version are you using while running the test.

Comment: I showed you a test case and an application that proves it works; it is using 4.3.22.BUILD-SNAPSHOT; you must have something wrong with your setup; I added the pom. I can't help you further unless you can share a simple project.

Comment: I am running the same sample project which you mentioned. I have uploaded demo project here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jFtX6BDBPio20FbNazeP_LMnNHsvj5LT

Comment: updated question with the logs which generated by this sample project.

Comment: The sample is working as expected in your logs `factory.setRefreshSharedInterval(15_000);` - means try to fail back every 15 seconds. We got the server2 connection at `21:57:39.084` and tried to fail back at `21:57:56.102`; set it to `Long.MAX_VALUE` to never fail back.

Comment: Gary, yes I agree its working as expected if we set 15_000 but its not working if we set Long.MAX_VALUE. Even its working if we set Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: Ouch! Sorry - you are correct I re-opened [the issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3199). In the meantime; `Integer.MAX_VALUE` will work.

Comment: Thanks Gary, when release build would be available for 4.3.22.

Comment: Hi Gary, any update for release build. When it would be available.

Comment: 4.3.22 is in maven central and the repo.spring.io.